# Building a component which depends on a 3rd party script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I'm using [react-async-script-loader](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader) to loading a 3rd party chat client and I'm currently simply using it as a HOC to the root of the react app. It works, but it doesn't feel React like.

#### Current Usage

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes, cloneElement } from 'react';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

const App extends Component {

   render() {
       return <div>React App</div>;
   }
}

export default scriptLoader('https://livechaturl.com/keyvalue')(App);
```

#### How I'd Like to Use It

```js
import React, { Children, Component } from 'react';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

const LiveChat extends Component {

   render() {
        return Children.only(this.props.children);
   }
}

export default scriptLoader(/* passed in value */)(LiveChat);


<LiveChat url="https://livechaturl.com/keyvalue">
    <App />
</LiveChat>
```

I don't want to have to hardcode the URL like I'm currently doing in the App component, but I can't seem to find an answer as to how to provide that prop value to the HOC of react-async-script-loader.

Is there an alternative way to use a HOC that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

With this specific component I'm not seeing how not having the script at build time.

What I would do perhaps is fork it and change it to use a prop so for example [here](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader/blob/master/src/index.js#L68), would be changed to :

```
const scriptLoader = (WrappedComponent) => {
  // ...
 }
```

And you would use the props [here](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader/blob/master/src/index.js#L91)

```
startLoadingScripts(this.props.scripts, err => {
  //...
}
```

Since we removed the first arg it would be instantiated like

```
export default scriptLoader(App);
```